# ngrok server doesn't connect with dialogfow

Tags: python, nlp, dialogflow-es, chatbot, ngrok

I am an absolute beginner in chat bot. I am learning on my own and went on developing a very simple chat bot using Dialog flow. I have a python code for responding the request to my Dialog flow bot. I have enabled "webhook" in fulfillment and also enabled in "Intent".My ngrok url is http://ae3df23b.ngrok.io/. I have written a function in my python code which respond to ngrok which connects Dialog flow. Now problem is that It is showing error "404 not found" and The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. Please help me guys. Thanks in advance.

My code is

```
    #import necessary packages and libraries
import urllib
import os
import json
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import make_response

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])

def webhook():
    req=request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)
    print("Request:")
    print(json.dumps(req, indent=4))
    res=makeWebhookResult(req)
    res=json.dumps(res, indent=4)
    print(res)
    r=make_response(res)
    r.headers['Content-Type']='application/json'
    return r

def makeWebhookResult(req):
    if req.get("result").get("action")!="interest":
        return {}
    result=req.get("result")
    parameters=result.get("parameters")
    name=parameters.get("Banknames")
    bank={'SBI':'10%', 'HDFC Bank':'9%', 'Bank of Baroda':'11', 'Federal Bank':'8.9%', 'ICICI Bank': '11.5%'}
    speech='The interest rate of '+ name + "is" + str(bank[name])
    print("Response:")
    print(speech)
    return {
    "speech":speech,
    "displayText":speech,
    "source":"BankInterestRates"
    }
if __name__ == "__main__":
    port=int(os.getenv('PORT', 80))
    print("Starting app on port %d", (port))

    app.run(debug=True, port=port, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: are you able to hit the service from Postman or Rest Console?

Comment: running from command line in my system

Comment: Can you update your question to show what command are you using to start ngrok and what is displayed on the command line when you run your python script?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `https://ae3df23b.ngrok.io/webhook`. You are missing the path. Also, use `https` and generate a new ngrok URL and update the fulfilment.

Comment: I have tried too... but still the same error @abhinav

Comment: try and change the port to 8080 or other

Comment: OK i will change the port and let u know. I have already updated the fulfillment every time i get a new URL tunnel

Comment: OK i will change the port and let u know. I have already updated the fulfillment every time i get a new URL tunnel

Comment: first check if you are able to communicate via postman or rest console. have a GET method for server pings

Comment: how to do it? please suggest me. I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this format instead https://ae3df23b.ngrok.io/[replace-with-your-project-id]/us-central1/dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment

and make sure u start ngrok with port 5000 and host your functions with "firebase serve" command